# How can we find contextual similarity between two different n-grams using python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, similarity

For example,
Suppose we have two words, 'great' and 'very good' which are contextually similar to each other but they are differenet n-grams (*'great' is unigram and 'very good' is bigram*). I need some suggestions on how to go about building a NLP model that can score the similarity between them.

Comment: this question is to broad for this place, sorry!

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not a recommendation, advice, or discussion forum; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can considering encoding your text using word2vec.

You can use pretrained model on Google news

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz
gunzip GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.
```

Usage:

```
import gensim

# Load Google's pre-trained Word2Vec model.
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./model/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True) 

corpus = [
'good person',
'good human being'
]
# For each sentence in corpus, generate a vector.
# using any similarity measure, you can compute similarity once you encode your text to vector.
corpus_vec = []
for sentence in corpus:
     sent_vec = np.zeros(300)
     for word in sentence:
        sent_vec += model[word]
     corpus_vec.append(sent_vec)
```

This gives you 300 dimensional vector for each word. Convert all the words in 300 dimensional vector and add them up for each text.

Now you can use cosine similarity or any other similarity measure.